# Can't use my new Logitech K750 when booting (GRUB) in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, boot, keyboard, grub2

Yes, My new Logitech K750 works allright when my OS (Ubuntu 11.04) is up.

But there's only one thing: when booting and going into the GRUB2 bootloader, I can't select options by using the arrow keys, nor can I use the 'e' for editing.

Especially annoying if one has a second OS to choose from.

Does anyone has a solution for this flaw? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Takkat! The trick was indeed to change the Bios setting from 'USB keyboard disabled' to 'enabled'. It would take me a lot of time to even think of finding the solution in the BIOS (although an obvious place to start looking). I'll keep that in mind for a possible next time. Thanks again! Cheers.

Comment: @Takkat - can you convert your comment to an answer so I can upvote it

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes we need to make appropriate BIOS settings to enable support for an USB keyboard.

Search for something like

> USB Device Legacy Support

to enable this option.

Note: you may eventually need an old PS/2 keyboard to be able to browse the BIOS settings.