# Keyboard not working at grub

Tags: wireless, grub2, keyboard, logitech

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't use my new Logitech K750 when booting (GRUB) in Ubuntu 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53353/cant-use-my-new-logitech-k750-when-booting-grub-in-ubuntu-11-04)

My keyboard is not working when I get to the grub screen my keyboard seems to disable and I'm unable to make a selectuon but if I enter the BIOS it works fine I have a Logitech. Wireless keyboard

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/a/109362/4982

Comment: I think the problem’s origin was just that the **default** keyboard configuration after updating grub (pangolin’s grub 1.99) does not right established **in this release**.
So I think it’s a bug and I warn you to fix it.
I had a similar problem with my spanish keyboard (not US kboard)

Answer (score 0):

I found this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1709532) reply from an earlier thread stating that the user removed and replaced their CMOS battery and everything worked fine.

Hope this helps!